# Connections between matrix and its inverse in $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix in $\textit{GL}(n, \mathbb{F}$). $A$ and $A^{-1}$ can be also viewed as a vectors in $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$. Are there any non-trivial connections between $A$ and $A^{-1}$ when viewed as vectors?

I am mostly interested in relations between $A^{-1}$ and $(M A)^{-1}$ where $M$ is in $\textit{GL}(n^2, \mathbb{F})$ and $M A$ is in $F^{n^2}$ viewed as an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: What's $\Bbb F$? Any field?

Comment: @xavierm02 some field.